# Why when I render my 200 frame animation everything is the world color and not the animation?

Tags: animation

Please Help
Why when I render my 200 frame animation everything is the world color and not the animation?  I have fully created the models and environment and when I run the animation in the UI under material it works fine,  when I try to animate the animation is just gives me grey frames.
I cannot figure out why it wont render the actual animation.

http://youtu.be/A5J8y4uCtsU

Comment: Is your camera outside of the background mesh? (looks like a dome maybe, with a texture?)

Comment: Could you please post a .blend file, it would really help us figure out what is wrong. You can use a service like http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It's very hard to guess from the video you posted, but there are some objects that are disabled for rendering (the camera icon on the outliner window)

Comment: ground is activated but invisible. check renderlayers, compositing and sequencer. else blend will be needed.

Comment: From the Outliner area in the video, I can see renderability for some objects are disabled, maybe you could try to enable the right ones. BTW, OSL is toggled in render panel, are you sure that's intended?

Comment: What composite nodes do you have?

Answer (score 1):

be sure that all  layers that contains your objects are selected in the **render_layer** tab"

[image]